# split list of numbers into two separate odd and even number lists using stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am studying Java8 and want to perform following operations using stream API in Java8.

Input: List of (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

### Output:
Odd List - (1,3,5,7,9)
Even List - (2,4,6,8)

I can do this operation in single for loop in traditional java like

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(3,4,2,5,6,7,4,5);
List<Integer> oddList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> evenList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Integer i : ints) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        evenList.add(i);
    } else {
        oddList.add(i);
    }
}
```

I know a way to do this in Java8 style as follows -

```
List<Integer> evens = ints.stream().filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> odds = ints.stream().filter(i -> i % 2 == 1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But here the problem is that I am iterating the ints twice instead of once. Is there a way that this can be done without iterating twice in streams?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) collector. It collects the stream into a map, which has 2 lists. One list contains elements that satisfy the predicate, the other contains those that don't.

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> partitions = ints.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(x -> x % 2 == 0));
List<Integer> evens = partitions.get(true);
List<Integer> odds = partitions.get(false);
```

Comment: Just curious. What if we need a three sublists? like oddList, evenList and negativeList?

Comment: Create an enum with a value for each list, and write a function which returns an enum, replacing the function returning a boolean above.

Comment: If they are disjoint groups (i.e. negatives are neither odd nor even), you can use `groupingBy`. @Harish